# Bulk registration or disallow registering of certain usernames

Tags: 7, users

I need to register 1000+ usernames at once.
How to do it?

Or is there any way to disallow from registering 1000+ usernames? People could not register certain usernames.

I need to reserve these usernames for payed registration.

Comment: For example I have a list like this: username1, username2, userhame3 ... username1000.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by code, alter the registration form (***hook_form_user_register_form_alter***), in a custom module like:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['validate'][] = 'reserved_usernames';
}
```

And then implement the validation (in the same MY_MODULE.module file) method like:

```
function reserved_usernames ($form, &$form_state) {
  $reserved = array();
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name';
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name_1';
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name_2';
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name_3';
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name_4';
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name_5';

  if (in_array($form_state['values']['name'], $reserved)) {
    form_set_error('name', t('The name %name cannot be taken.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name'])));
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean I need to make a special module? rémy, I do not understand  how and where to add my list of usernames which I need to reserve.

Comment: yes - you need to make a custom module, or this code could also be placed in your theme, but I would not suggest that. I updated the question to show you the use with an array.

Comment: But I do not understand how and where to add restricted usernames. A list of disallowed usernames. 1000 or 2000 usernames.

Comment: the array $reserved contains the restricted names. this also could be loaded form DB of where ever ...

Comment: But there is only single username  in your sample. I talk about bulk registration or reservation.

Comment: you can repeat this line as often as you want to fill up the array. `$reserved[] = 'reserved_name_2';`

Comment: Not clear anyway. Sorry. I have a list of 1000  usernames. How and where to add it? :)

Comment: I have upVoted but can not accept this.

Comment: I have upVoted but can not accept this. It is better to hand add users in admin panel than to do it in so difficult way. Also I  was not able to activate and test this module because of error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /sites/all/modules/reserved_usernames/reserved_usernames.module on line 18

Comment: My code in module:

Comment: <?php

function reserved_usernames_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['validate'][] = 'reserved_usernames';
}

function reserved_usernames ($form, &$form_state) {
  $reserved = array();
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name';
  $reserved[] = 'reserved_name_1';

  if (in_array($form_state['values']['name'], $reserved)) {
    form_set_error('name', t('The name %name cannot be taken.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['name'])))
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46616/discussion-between-remy-and-ttt).